# Getting hold of a reference to the object created by JOptionPane static methods

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I wonder if it is possible to get hold of a reference to the (JDialog?) object created by one of those static methods of JOptionPane (e.g. showMessageDialog)? I intend to modify the position where the dialog appears on the screen. More specifically, I want the dialog to appear at the top-left corner of the main app window, instead of the centre of the window by default. So having a reference to the object would enable me to use setLocation to achieve the desired effect...

Any suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The static `showXXXDialog()` methods are just for convenience.  If you look at the source code for `JOptionPane`, you'll find that in actuality, a `JOptionPane` object is created based on the options you specify and then `JOptionPane.createDialog(...)` is called.  One method to show your message dialog at a different position is:

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("TITLE");
dialog.setLocation(0, 0);
dialog.setVisible(true);

// dialog box shown here

dialog.dispose();
Object selection = pane.getValue();
```

With a combination of parameters to the `JOptionPane` constructor, and `JOptionPane` set methods, you can do anything you would have done with the static methods, plus you have access to the `JDialog` object itself.

**EDITED**: (to add example of input dialog for OP)

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Message", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, null, null, null);
pane.setWantsInput(true);
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Title");
dialog.setLocation(0, 0);
dialog.setVisible(true);

String str = (String) pane.getInputValue();
```

Comment: Cool, I can see how I can apply the above to showMessageDialog, showConfirmDialog, etc. But what about implementing showInputDialog? How do I implement an input text field in JDialog?

Comment: @user548240 - added example of inputDialog

Comment: Cool, I was thinking about constructing it from scratch and didn't know there are methods readily available in JOptionPane. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The JOptionPane will use the given `parentComponent` (first method parameter) to determine where to center the dialog (for example in javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component, Object))

You could try to pass in a fake component which positions the dialog to another location, for example like this:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLocation(100, 100);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // 'Invisible' fake component for positioning
    JWindow c = new JWindow();
    c.setSize(0, 0);
    c.setVisible(true);
    Point location = frame.getLocation();
    location.translate(200, 100);
    c.setLocation(location);

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(c,"Foo");
```