# How can I dismiss one JOptionPane upon emergence of another JOptionPane in the GUI

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

As you have seen from my subject above,
I would like to know how can I dismiss a JOptionPane which became irrelevant because of another JOptionPane and because the user ,for some reason, didn't dismiss the first one by himself clicking ok button (for example).

I've seen some ware in other site similar question, and people suggested to do simply:

```
JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
```

But how can I store a reference for each JOptionPane I have and to be able to dismiss only that wanted one.
Thanks

Edited:
Code example:

```
package Gui;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class JpanelMainView extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /** Creates new form JpanelMainView */
    public JpanelMainView() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(149, 149, 149)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(178, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(200, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                         
    {                                             
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Board was sent for validation check\n Please wait...","Board Sent",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

       //Please note that this OptionPane is coming in my real program always after the first JoptionPane
       //I want that if I've reached the line in the code that need to show this second JoptionPane, I will first close the first JoptionPane
       //Else you will dismiss the last JoptionPane and then the first one and I don't want to give the user two JoptionPane to close, it's annoying.
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Set your move now please","Game started",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }                                        

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: A JOptionPane is usually modal (there are exceptions of course), so I wonder how the user was even able to bring up a second JOptionPane when the first one is visible? Can you create and post a small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem and that we can test, modify and possibly correct, an [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: okay I have generated really simple working example where should I upload it?

Comment: @JavaSa: Edit your post and include it.

Comment: Thanks for your SSCCE. I've modified the code in my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend that you

- create a JDialog with your JOptionPane (the [JOptionPane API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) will show you how),
- then use a SwingWorker for whatever background task you wish to do that should be done off of the main Swing thread, the EDT,
- Then in the SwingWorker's `done()` method which is called when the background task is complete, dispose of the JDialog.
- Then the next JOptionPane will be called immediately.

For example the following code uses a Thread.sleep(3000) for a 3 second sleep to mimic a background task that takes 3 seconds. It will then close the first dialog and show the second:

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      JOptionPane messagePane = new JOptionPane(
            "Board was sent for validation check\n Please wait...",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      final JDialog dialog = messagePane.createDialog(this, "Board Sent");

      new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // do your background processing here
            // for instance validate your board here

            // mimics a background process that takes 3 seconds
            // you would of course delete this in your actual progam
            Thread.sleep(3000); 

            return null;
         }

         // this is called when background thread above has completed.
         protected void done() {
            dialog.dispose();
         };
      }.execute();

      dialog.setVisible(true);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Set your move now please",
            "Game started", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
```

Comment: I guess I don't need the swing worker because my background task is being held in my Server, after it was validating the Board it returns an ok Ack to the client Gui and the game automatically begin

Comment: I'm not so sure that you won't need a SwingWorker or some sort of background thread. How does your GUI code tell the Server to validate the board? Does it do so in a blocking way or is it in a non-blocking way? How does the GUI wait for the server's response? How is it notified? All these things can tie up your Swing event thread. But,... it's your application, so do it as you see fit.

Comment: Okay I trying to make things more clear,when my Gui is connecting at first to my server it open new listening thread (runnable implementation) in the client that is waiting for coming command in the DataInputStream by simple calling to readInt function on the m_InputStream member. The Gui tell the server to validate the board on a special board building screen after clicking on a swing button "validate board" it's blocking because I need the second Player of the table to build his own board for opponent and only then to

Comment: start a game when two boards were built by both player sitting next to a game table. so it's blocking I guess by I don't need my gui responsive after the sending, just need to wait, so I don't think that uploading my board after clicking the validate button will cause the Gui to be unresponsive, cause all these actions are really fast, what do you think?

Comment: If they're very fast, then no need for a JOptionPane to tell the player to wait for validation. If otherwise, then you'll need a background thread. But only you can tell. If your program freezes noticeably at any point, then that indicates need for a thread. Either way, much luck!

Comment: No ,the waiting is for the rival player to finish building his board for you- not for validation acknowledgment of your own board only. Only when the two boards were validated they are being sent in the same time by the server to each client of the two players in crossbreeding way each board the users have built for its rivals and the game begin. I guess that not every fast communication code that is launched from JbuttonActionPerformed (EDT) is a prohibited act.Am I right?
Anyway it's little bit late here, so I will try things tomorrow and will update you :)

Comment: +1, this one is a good alternative, though this answer did put me in a confusion, while answering on another thread :-), I used a `Timer` instead of `SwingWorker`, so wondering about my approach being bad :-)

Answer (score 4):

simple answer, that not possible, because only one `JOptionPane` can exist in current time, if you want to solve your issue, then you have to create `JDialog#ModalityType(Aplications???)` or `JWindow` then you'll able to shows `JOptionPane`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ClosingFrame extends JFrame {

    private JMenuBar MenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JMenu File = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuItem Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    private JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();

    public ClosingFrame() {
        File.add(Exit);
        MenuBar.add(File);
        Exit.addActionListener(new ExitListener());
        WindowListener exitListener = new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                        "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                        "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
                if (confirm == 0) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        };
        frame.addWindowListener(exitListener);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setJMenuBar(MenuBar);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame1.addWindowListener(exitListener);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame1.setLocation(500, 100);
        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ExitListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                    "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Whatever", "Whatever",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            int confirm1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame1,
                    "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                    "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            if (confirm == 0) {
                //System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ClosingFrame cf = new ClosingFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, but what about using some manipulation like in the accepted answer of post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542924/getting-hold-of-a-reference-to-the-object-created-by-joptionpane-static-methods , will it solve my problem?

Comment: I guess because only one JoptionPane can exist that post can't help

Comment: @JavaSa `1)` basically is possible to hide JOptionPane, `2)` nobody to guaranteed that which code block will be executed current or previous from hidded JOptionPane, `3)` this Component is there for bloking code executions (work as semaphore), block user_input, `4)` last property is to call (custom JOptionPane with manually added JButton(s)) myButton.doClick();, then JOptionPane gone away `5)` I think that solve nothing (link that you posted) :-)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I don't understand your question well, do you mean that you want to close one JOptionPane from another one?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUIProgram extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton btn1, btn2, btn3;
    private static final String BUTTON1_COMMAND = "Press it!";
    private static final String BUTTON2_COMMAND = "show new JOptionPane!";
    private static final String BUTTON3_COMMAND = "close old JOptionPane!";
    private JOptionPane pane1, pane2;

    public GUIProgram()
    {
        super("The title");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btn1 = new JButton(BUTTON1_COMMAND);
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn1.setActionCommand(BUTTON1_COMMAND);

        btn2 = new JButton(BUTTON2_COMMAND);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.setActionCommand(BUTTON2_COMMAND);

        btn3 = new JButton(BUTTON3_COMMAND);
        btn3.addActionListener(this);
        btn3.setActionCommand(BUTTON3_COMMAND);

        pane1 = new JOptionPane();
        pane2 = new JOptionPane();

        getContentPane().add(btn1);
        setSize(200, 100);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new GUIProgram();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals(BUTTON1_COMMAND))
        {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(btn2);
            pane1.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "JOptionPane #1", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);
        }

        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals(BUTTON2_COMMAND))
        {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(btn3);
            pane2.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "JOptionPane #2", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);
        }

        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals(BUTTON3_COMMAND))
        {
            pane1.getRootFrame().dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No,I meant that if the user is not fast enough to click ok on one JoptionPane it will stay on background, after sometime he will get another optionPane and then he will need to close two JoptionPanes, therefore I want to be able to cancel previous JoptionPane if that second JoptionPane already came in(and the user didn't dismiss the first one)