# Making a Dialog Visible and then Invisible

Tags: java, swing, visibility, jdialog

I was wondering if there's a simple way to make a Dialog visible for a very short period of time and then have it turn invisible. Or even if there's a possibility to do this instantaneously.

Cheers,
Kesh

Comment: You can use timer class. I am not sure what you really want.

Comment: Please have a look at this wonderful answer, regarding [Closing JOptionPane programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18107432/1057230) by @kleopatra, you just don't need the second `if` statement in the `for` loop , for your use case :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing A JOptionPane Programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105598/closing-a-joptionpane-programatically)

Comment: Seems to be, you guys are right. Is Stack etiquette to delete the question if it's a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

In a method do this:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    try {
     Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
    dialog.setVisible(false);
  }
t.start();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: please to delete this answer, 1) in Java7 isn't something visible until Thread.sleep(int) ended, 2) doesn't work in Java6 because all event to EDT are flushed in one moment when Thread.sleep(int) ended, 3) too lazy to remember for another side effects Thread.sleep(int) + visibility + EDT