# Timer or other idea required to allow code to continue execution after calling method and JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, timer, joptionpane

I need a way to allow my program to keep running code after this method is called.

Currently, it waits for half an hour, gets the info, stores it to the object WeatherCard, and displays it, and repeats.  But it hangs on the JOptionPane.  I need a way to make it so that the program either keeps going underneath the JOptionPane or to close the pane after about 10 seconds.  I am not sure how to work either into my code, currently

```
public void printWeatherCard(WeatherCard w, JFrame controlFrame) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
    /* Displays a dialog box containing the temperature and location */
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL(w.imgSrc));
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controlFrame, "It is currently " + w.currentTemp + " \u00B0 F in " + w.location.city + ", " + w.location.state + ".\nCurrent humidity: " + w.currentHumidity + 
            "%.\nChance of precipitation: " + w.chancePrecip + "%.", "Weather Update: " + w.location.zipCode, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it hangs on the JOptionPane. I need a way to make it so that the
>   program either keeps going underneath the JOptionPane or to close the
>   pane after about 10 seconds. I am not sure how to work either into my
>   code, currently

there are two ways

- (better easier, comfortable) create `JDialog(JFrame parent, boolean true)`, with default close operation `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`, only one `JDialog` as `local variabl`e, reuse this `Object` by `setVisible(false/true)`
- [looping inside arrays of all JOptionPanes (all exists there untill current JVM is alive)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18107432/714968) by `@kleopatra`

Comment: I decided to go with a custom JDialog (thought it will require quite a bit of reworking things in my program).  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Closing a modal dialog after some delay and updating the display behind a modal dialog are *distinct* issues.

- In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513), a `javax.swing.Timer` is used to mark time, and the dialog is closed when a counter reaches zero or the user dismisses it.
- A modal dialog only blocks *user* interaction. Add a modal dialog to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616169/230513) to see that GUI updates continue in response to the `javax.swing.Timer`.

  ```
  public void run() {
      ...
      f.setVisible(true);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dt, TITLE);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

JOptionPane is modal, which means code execution blocks until the user dismisses or acknowledges it.  You need to use a non-modal dialog.  Consider creating your own JDialog. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: A modal dialog only blocks _user_ interaction, not execution.

Comment: @trashgod - It does block execution on the current thread.  In the code Nick posted his program was waiting on the JOptionPane, which halted the execution of his code.

Comment: Place a modal dialog before the setVisible on the Jframe, inside the random bubbdle method, or inside the action listener code all halt execution of your example.  If you place it in the paintComponent code you'll see repeated popups but the paintComponent code is halted each time.  In each instance the current thread is waiting on input and will not execute code until the user acknowledges the modal dialog.  I suspect that placing it after the setVisible does not block because at that point the timer is already running and the RepaintManager is intercepting all of the repaint calls.

Comment: It's certainly _possible_ to block the EDT, but the `JOptionPane` itself doesn't do so. Sorry if I'm missing your point. I suspect that @Nick's "custom `JDialog`" means a _modeless_ dialog, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513).