# How is a JDialog's owner still updating it's UI even when it's EDT is blocked?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have the following example code:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public MainWindow() {
       JButton openButton = new JButton('Open');
       openButton.addActionListener(this);
       add(openButton);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       // Create and show a modal dialog.
       JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, true);
       dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I click the `openButton` it calls `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` on the event dispatch thread and `dialog.setVisible(true)` blocks it.

But with more sophisticated frames I notice that they still update their UI from non user generated events such as a Timer action.

In any other case that I block the EDT my UI completely hangs, but when `dialog.setVisible(true)` blocks the EDT the owner's UI continues to update.

So my question is how does this work?

Comment: It creates it's own event queue

Comment: @ MadProgrammer Thank you for your response, but can you be more specific with "it" and how does that make the owner respond to events?

Comment: Your Timer was started before the modal dialog was shown, correct?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels yes

Comment: Basically, the dialog creates it's own Event Queue and filters the events coming through it.  You can open the source code and take a look

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18728637/230513).

Comment: its about good practicies to delay pack(); and setVisible(true); into invokeLater