# How to pause program execution without blocking a Timer (Java Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, thread-sleep

I have a Timer that shows an animation on the screen when a game event takes place. What I want to do is have the main execution pause until this animation finishes, but everything I try seems to block the Timer from running. I've tried using Thread.sleep() and calling wait() and notify() on a lock object, but with the same result. The Timer listener's actionPerformed() is never called.

This code sets up the timer:

```
protected void showMovingEffect(int steps, Direction dir, AnimatedImageSet imgs) {
    effectsPane.runAnimation(imgs, dir, steps);
    waiting = true;
    while (waiting) {
        synchronized(animationWaitLock) {
            try {
                animationWaitLock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

And the Timer and listener inside the EffectsPane object:

```
private void runAnimation(AnimatedImageSet ais, Direction dir, int iters) {
        System.out.println("run");
        imgs = ais;
        top = 0;
        left = 0;
        topStep = dir.getRowIncrement() * 10;
        leftStep = dir.getColIncrement() * 10;
        iterations = iters;
        index = 0;
        active = true;
        timer.start();
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(index);
        top += topStep;
        left += leftStep;
        index++;
        currentImage = imgs.getImage(index);
        repaint();
        if (index == iterations) { 
            active = false;
            timer.stop();
            synchronized(animationWaitLock) {
                animationWaitLock.notify();
            }
            waiting = false;
        }
    }
```

The System.out.println call at the start of the actionPerformed() is never called, so either the wait() call is also pausing the Timer, or something is blocking it. If I comment out the sleep/wait lines in showMovingEffect(), the animation runs, but the program does not pause.

Comment: DON'T USE SLEEP!!!!!

Comment: I'm not. I'm using wait().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to display a [modal dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) while the animation proceeds. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18728637/230513), user interaction will be foreclosed, but background GUI updates in response to the [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) will continue. You can allow the user to dismiss the dialog at any time, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513), but you may want to abandon the animation at that point.

> no input from the user is needed.

You can block user interaction without displaying a dialog by entering a [`SecondaryLoop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SecondaryLoop.html) after the animation starts.

```
SecondaryLoop loop = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
    .getSystemEventQueue().createSecondaryLoop();
timer.start();
loop.enter();
```

When the animation concludes, `exit()` the `SecondaryLoop`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    …
    if (index == iterations) {
        timer.stop();
        loop.exit ();
        …
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for, I'm afraid. I'm looking for a way to pause after starting the timer, and restart when it finishes. Having a dialog box would serve no purpose, as no input from the user is needed.

Comment: @Leonide: I'm wary of blocking user interaction with no visual feedback or escape mechanism; but for a short animation, you can use a `SecondaryLoop` as outlined above.

Comment: Possibly tangential question. The first thing I tried with this was to have the runAnimation method have a loop that periodically refreshed the effectsPane, but with this, it was pause like I wanted, but the effectsPane wouldn't refresh. Any idea why?

Comment: @Leonide: At a guess, the loop blocked the existing event queue; a `SecondaryLoop` blocks user interaction but lets the animation proceed.

Comment: +++ 1mio for SecondaryLoop :-), [now is searchable here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bswing%5d%20SecondaryLoop), there, everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // your code
    }
});
```

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: because on this code, this actionPerformed is your method, not acction listener method. so if you want to run it, you must call `effectsPane.actionPerformed(java.awt.Event);` like `effectsPane.runAnimation(imgs, dir, steps);` or add @Override to your actionPerformed method

Comment: Tried this, but with the same result. The actionPerformed method still isn't getting called. Does it matter whether the Timer is a member of the class calling showMovingEffect or the JPanel showing the animation?