# Java Swing [JDialog]

Tags: java, swing, hide, dispose, jdialog

I can't hide or dispose `JDialog`, If I set `JDialog` with `Boolean Modal = true;` otherwise if I set JDialog with `Boolean Modal = false` I can hide or dispose, but then overriden method `paint()` doesn't do what I want.

I Tried to `SetModal()`, but it doesn't succed.
I forgot I had extended `JPanel` on `JDialog`.

```
NewJDialog dialog = new NewJDialog(this, true); // here
```

in NewJDialog I have private NewJPanel newJPanel1;
which has overwritten method paint in NewJPanel

Comment: this sound me like as nonsence, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about empty JFrame and empty modal JDialog caused with a.m. issue

Comment: Please try to add a demo of your code

Comment: This wonderful [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18107432/1057230), I hope will surely address your concern :-)

Comment: Incidentally, "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 2):

Let your panel be a *listener* to the modeless dialog, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513).

Comment: +1 for this new approach, though my vote will come in some time (Limit gone for the day __:(__) Learning many new thingies, now a days, surely this thingy (pattern) is something I just learned quite recently :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw: Thanks for looking at this (now closed) Q&A; the user may not realize that `setModalityType(MODELESS)`, formerly `setModal(false)`, leaves the observer pattern implementation to the application.