# Automatically closing Jdialog without user action

Tags: java, swing, timer, jdialog

I'm creating an application in which I test a certain number of interface features, and when an error occurs I would like an error message to show.
Then the application should take a screenshot of the entire screen, and finally the error message closes without any help from the user.

To this end, I tried to use JDialog as below:

```
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Error message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("Error");
    dialog.addWindowListener(null);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    Application.takeScreenshot();
    dialog.setVisible(false);
```

I was wondering if there is a specific method to close it. I looked up the documentation and I can't seem to find it.  I tried to find a relevant question on SO, but couldn't find one that addresses my problem.

I wonder if there is a way to get the window handle, and then close it using that, or simply send a "CLOSE" or "Press_ok" event to the window?

Edit: It seems to me as if the code entirely stops running when the messagebox shows, as if there was a Thread.sleep() until window is closed manually by the user.

If possible, a code sample would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at this wonderful [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18105598/1057230), which surely does it's job in a much better way :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `ScheduledExecutorService`. Something like:

```
    JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("Error");
    dialog.addWindowListener(null);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

ScheduledExecutorService sch = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();     
sch.schedule(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        dialog.setVisible(false);
        dialog.dispose();
    }
}, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

dialog.setVisible(true);
```

**[EDIT]**

Regards to camickr comment, the documentation does not mention that a `ScheduledExedcutorService` executes on the Event Dispatch Thread. So better to use `swing.Timer`

```
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("Error");
 dialog.addWindowListener(null);
 dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() { // 10 sec
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialog.setVisible(false);
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });

        timer.start();

        dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: could be with side effects in Java7 for longer delay, then dialog.whatever will be called out of EDT

Comment: Good hint, I never used more then 20 sec, have doc. reference?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType%28java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29

Comment: All Swing updates should execute on the EDT. The documentation does not mention that a ScheduledExedcutorService executes on the EDT. So instead you should be using a `Swing Timer`.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix it. It seems that by default, JDialog is Modal, meaning that it interrupts everything else until it's closed by the user. To fix this, I used the method:

```
dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
```

When this is active, a simple  .setVisible(false); is enough.
Anyways thanks for the help sorry for creating an unecessary question but I had been at it for hours until i found it. Hope it can help others.

Comment: Setting the `JDialog` to false is not sufficient enough, since it will still remain. Disposing it off is the way to go. Moreover, the example cited in the link above provided by me, doesn't have adhere to whether the `JDialog` is modal or not.